# How does the Paypal 'Mobile Phone and PIN' login work?

Tags: applications

The [Paypal app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paypal.android.p2pmobile&hl=en) has a two ways you can log in, 'Email and Password' and 'Mobile Phone and PIN'.

How does the second one work? I can't seem to set a PIN code myself and it doesn't use the one from my phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you gotta login to the PayPal app on your phone.
(In this case, obviously, your Android device ;) )

Next up, you gotta visit your PayPal account settings through your web-browser
(The gear on the top right)
[image]

Then, you gotta go over to the "Security" tab and click on "Mobile Devices"
[image]

From there on you should be able to figure out how it works.
I haven't linked my mobile with PayPal yet, so I can't help from here on.